# What is the state of the art precaution to try out dubious software most likely safely today?

Tags: windows, virtualization, sandbox, windows-10

I want to try out **dubious** software on my windows 10 computer.

(Bold parts are keywords for the TL/DR fraction)

What is the state of the art **precaution** to do this most likely safely today?

The software I want to install requires **admin rights** to install. I did some research and it was conflicting, so I decided to not share it to not influence the answers.

To make this specific.

1. Is a **sandbox** like sandboxie sufficient when I use my computer with admin rights and uac.
2. Is a **virtual environment** like virtualbox sufficient when I use my computer with admin rights and uac.
3. Should I create another user **without admin rights**?
4. Should I try to **remove the admin requirements from the exe** and go to 1-3?

What are best practises today?

Comment: If it's not big, try virustotal.com. If it has virus, just don't try to run it.

Comment: @Aria virustotal just detects the most common malware. If the software is new, I need a different approach. Also, false positive are common for virustotal.

Comment: If it's not big, one can try to decompile it. If it's .NET, one can try .NET Reflector.

Comment: buy a $100 computer and test it there

Comment: @dandavis Where do you get $100 computers and how would I know that something is safe just because it seems safe?

Comment: well at some point you need to trust _something_. $100 can buy a new compute stick, a used computer locally, or a [refurb from newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Desktop-Computers/SubCategory/ID-10?Order=PRICE), or amazon et al.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how thoroughly you'd like to try them out. I'm going to assume that you're not looking to understand everything about how the application works, but are more interested in taking it for a spin without cryptolockering yourself.

My suggestion would be to use a non-networked VM. VirtualBox or Hyper-V are both free, and you can download trial versions of Windows [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/try).

If you wanted to get a bit more thorough, you could look at outbound DNS queries from your VM for shady domains.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you different solutions, from the most secure (and most expensive) to the less secure (but simplest).

1. use a dedicated hardware machine. In corporate environments, it is common to have have some old machines waiting for being thrown to bin. Disconnect it from the network, do your tests and reinstall. At most the software was terrible and managed to physically harm the machine, but it is quite uncommon
2. use a virtual machine with no network connection. It is almost the same as previous use case, except for 2 threats:

   - if it could harm the hardware, your real hardware was damaged, but as a virtual machine normally present virtual hardware the risk is low
   - if it contains malware directly targetted to the virtualizer that you use, anything can happen. But here again the risk is low
3. Use a mere sandbox as sandboxie. The problem here, is that sandboxie will let you *run* the application in a protected environment, but as the installation has to write something to the disk, you cannot use the sandbox for the install part. That means that if the installation program installs a malware in addition to the program, you have lost
4. Just... pray and install without further precaution. Well a bit joking, but plenty of users only do that or at best rely on last saved data.

My advice would be 1 if you can afford it, or 2. As I have seen more programs *installing* malware beside them than actually *containing* it, I would not make that difference between 3 and 4